# Mysql ranking based on two columns

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck trying to figure out a way to assign a rank based on two values. My table is as follow:

```
---------------------------------------
| id | Student | Tasks | Errors | Rank |
---------------------------------------
| 1  | Vegeta  | 80    | 1500   | 18.7 |
---------------------------------------
| 2  | Ria     | 100   | 150    | 1.5  |
---------------------------------------
| 3  | John    | 200   | 300    | 1.5  |
---------------------------------------
| 4  | Goku    | 24    | 100    | 4.16 |
---------------------------------------
| 5  | Piccolo | 80    | 148    | 1.85 |
---------------------------------------
```

the rank value was calculated dividing errors/task so i can have an idea of the best student, but, John and Ria have the same rank yet John is a better student, as he has done more tasks than Ria, so I need to assign him rank 1 - ria would be rank 2 - Piccolo Rank 3 - goku rank 4 and Vegeta rank 5.

I tried

```
SELECT * from students ORDER BY Task DESC, Errors ASC
```

but only sorted it by `Task`, and it seems to ignore the second value, sorting by `rank` would be ok, but then how i can assign the proper order?

the new `rank` to be assigned should be based on Max number of task Vs. Min number of Errors, so a student with more Tasks and less errors should be on rank 1, and so on.

Comment: It is not clear how you want to compute your rankings.  Please include expected output.  Your sample query is behaving as would be expected.

Comment: Hey Tim, the ranking would be more tasks versus less errors, while more task and less errors a user have, higher would be the rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
select t.*, @r := @r + 1 as `new_rank`
from  tbl t,
(select @r := 0) r
order by `Rank` asc, `Tasks` desc
```

**Demo** [`sqlfiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e313/6)

If you don,t have `rank` (`Errors` / `Tasks`) column then;

```
select 
  `id`, `Student`, `Tasks`, `Errors`,
  @r := @r + 1 as `rank`
from  tbl t,
(select @r := 0) r
order by (`Errors` / `Tasks`) asc, `Tasks` desc
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ea70/9)

If you only want to `order` your result then;

```
order by `Rank` asc, `Tasks` desc
```

of

```
order by (`Errors` / `Tasks`) asc, `Tasks` desc
```

**Edit**
If a new user have only 20 task and 0 error?

```
select t.*, @r := @r + 1 as `new_rank`
from  tbl t,
(select @r := 0) r
order by 
  case when `rank` = 0 then 0 else 1 end desc, 
  `Rank` asc, `Tasks` desc
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c22a/4)

Comment: This work great, but i found a issue, if a new user have only 20 task and 0 error, then he gain rank 1, and he shouldnt as he have just a few tasks in comparation with John. updated demo [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c22a/1

Comment: Yes as the the best student is the one with more Tasks and less errors, so a student with 10 task and 0 errors is way below one with 200 task and 300 errors, i think.

Comment: It work great! Thanks!. But i will need to re think the whole thing, as now in the demo i see that Goku have 24 task and 100 errors and Tony 20 task and 0 errors, between them Tony should be first than Goku. But thats is another problem, the answer is the right to the question. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Use your calculation in **ORDER BY**

```
SELECT * from students
ORDER BY (Errors / Task), Task DESC;
```

**Results:**

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from students;
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
| id | Student | Task | Errors | Rank |
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
|  1 | Vegeta  |   80 |   1500 | 18.7 |
|  2 | Ria     |  100 |    150 |  1.5 |
|  3 | John    |  200 |    300 |  1.5 |
|  4 | Goku    |   24 |    100 | 4.16 |
|  5 | Piccolo |   80 |    148 | 1.85 |
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM students
    -> ORDER BY (ERRORS / Task), Task DESC;
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
| id | Student | Task | Errors | Rank |
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
|  3 | John    |  200 |    300 |  1.5 |
|  2 | Ria     |  100 |    150 |  1.5 |
|  5 | Piccolo |   80 |    148 | 1.85 |
|  4 | Goku    |   24 |    100 | 4.16 |
|  1 | Vegeta  |   80 |   1500 | 18.7 |
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: That is the same value on the rank column, the problem there is that two students can can have the same overall, like the case of John and Ria.

Comment: No, if the overall rank is the same it use the field Task for the suborder

Comment: i have added the results in my answer. is that not what you looking for ?

Comment: for some reason it dont work for me on mysql 5.6.12. It sort only the first argument, errors/task, it ignore the task DESC, plus i notice that if there is a student with 1 task and 0 error it goes to the first place. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58848/1